# RecyclerView quantity of alive binded items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I am creating a shared element transition animation, and I need that the recycler view to increase the quantity of elements that are binded. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview by his nature will recycle your viewholder after is outside of view.

You can try to cache them

```
int count = ...
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(count);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working as I need. Once they are cached they are removed from the view, and they are inserted back again when necessary.

Comment: That's is how recyclerview is working and for that was intended.

Comment: I am totally aware, but that is exactly the behaviour I need to avoid because I need the views off screen, but only a couple not all of them. I think that the only one solution I will have to achieve the animation will be creating new views and adding them in the given coordinates to emulate their positions.

Comment: You also can use a `ScrollView` where you add programmatically your items into a vertical `LinearLayout`. All the items are available, but your memory and performance will be affected. I recommand you this if you know you have a small and fixed amount of items.

Comment: I had thought about it too, sadly this time we are talking about a task that consumes a lot of memory.